# How to avoid formatting in XTEXT file if there are compilation errors?

Tags: java, xtext

I have create XTEXT project. I have written a formatter to format a dsl when I press ctrl + f.

But I want to avoid the formatting if there is an error in the dsl.
In what way I can to prevent formatting in case of compilation errors in dsl?

In my formatter class, I am extending `AbstractDeclarativeFormatter` and trying to override `createFormatterStream`, but I don't understand how to avoid formatting with this.

```
@Override
    public ITokenStream createFormatterStream(EObject context, String indent, ITokenStream out,
            boolean preserveWhitespaces) {
        if (!context.eResource().getErrors().isEmpty()) {
            // what should I return here?
        }
        return super.createFormatterStream(context, indent, out, preserveWhitespaces);
    }
```

Can someone guide me how to avoid formatting if a dsl is having error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: something similar to the impl in org.eclipse.xtext.formatting.impl.NullFormatter
does not work. did you consider to use the new formatter2 api?

Comment: NullFormatter works for me. Thanks alot